# AngularJS Uncaught ReferenceError: controller is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs

I'm trying to prepare the infrastructure needed to record the data in base using Web Api... And my question is why is getting this error:

> ReferenceError: WebApi is not defined
>       at Scope.$scope.salvar (Controller.js:22)
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15500), :4:138)
>       at callback (angular.js:27285)
>       at Scope.$eval (angular.js:18372)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18472)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (angular.js:27290)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)

My code is:

Controller.js

```
prontuariogestanteapp.controller("ProntuariogCtrl", ["$scope", "CalculadorIMC", "WebApi", function ($scope, calculadorIMC, WebApi) 
{
    $scope.tabs = [
        { Title: "Dados Básicos", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Dados_Basicos.html" },
        { Title: "1º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_1.html" },
        { Title: "2º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_2.html" },
        { Title: "3º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_3.html" },
        { Title: "4º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_4.html" },
        { Title: "5º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_5.html" },
        { Title: "6º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_6.html" },
        { Title: "7º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_7.html" },
        { Title: "8º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_8.html" },
        { Title: "9º Mês", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes_9.html" },
        { Title: "Pós-Parto", PageToDisplay: "./Html/Mes10_Pos_Parto.html" }
    ];

    $scope.salvar = function()
    {
        WebApi.salvar($scope.Mes1);
    };
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive: the reference (variable) you're trying to use (call) does not exist in scope of a function. From the code, it's hard to understand why, but looks like it's never been defined. Therefore, it is clearly a [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError).

Comment: True,but i really dont know what to do since i already named him on the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$scope.salvar = function WebApi()
{
    WebApi.salvar($scope.Mes1);

};
```

to

```
$scope.salvar = function()
{
    WebApi.salvar($scope.Mes1);

};
```

You can't name a method twice ($scope.salvar and WebApi).

Comment: I already did,but isnt working... Isnt recognizing the WebApi controller

Comment: I did. I put him on Service.js and on the ValuesController.cs

Answer (score 0):

After you resolve @Jasper Seinhorst suggestion you must check the following:

1. The **js** file where WebApi service is included properly in your **index.html**
2. Your **WebApi** service is stored inside a module; ensure that module is a **dependency** for the module where you want to use it